# connection from FlipSideView to tab2

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, flipside

I've created a Tab Bar application (2 tabs) then merged a Utility Application to it. So now i have an App with two tabs and a Flip animation.

When the App loads, Tab1 has the info button and on ButtonPressInfo the view flips giving me a FlipSideView with no tabs. What im stuck on is, i wish to press the "Done" button on FlipSideView but return to the second tab.

Ive tried several examples but I always get the same result, that is when you press the "Done" button it always returns to first tab.

```
testing123AppDelegate = (Testing123AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *vcs = [testing123AppDelegate.tabBarController viewControllers];
[[vcs objectAtIndex:1] viewWillDisappear:TRUE];
[self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your delegate's implementation of `flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:`, add a line like this:

```
myTabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

You might also have a look at the `selectedViewController` property on UITabBarController.

Comment: thank you so much, thats done the job. I can go to sleep now!